# how to query array population mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

./models/info-hotspot.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Scene = require('../models/scene');

var schemaInfoHotspot = new Schema({
  scene: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Scene', required: true },
  title: { type: String, require: false }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('InfoHotspot', schemaInfoHotspot);
```

./models/scene.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var InfoHotspot = require('../models/info-hotspot');

var schemaScene = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    infoHotspots: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'InfoHotspot',
            required: false
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Scene', schemaScene);
```

Query

```
  Scene
  .find()
  //.populate('infoHotspots')
  //.populate({
    //path: 'infoHotspots',
    //model: 'InfoHotspot'
  //})
  .exec(function(err, doc){
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    else  console.log(doc);
  });
```

All of its return infoHotspots: [ [Object], [Object]]
(Just work without array)

What's the reason?
How to solve this problem?

I want this result:

```
 Scenes = {
              "name": "scene-1",
              "infoHotspots": [
                {
                  "title": "my title1"
                },
                {
                  "title": "my title2"
                },
                {
                  "title": "my title3"
                }
              ]
         }
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Are you trying to filter out results using infoHotspots from scene relation? Can you give us an idea of what you are trying to get as an output?

Comment: i want to get infoHotspots array in Scenes JSON, like example above

Comment: if you uncomment .populate('infoHotspots') from your find query, does it return you a reference infoHotspots. The way you have setup the relationship that each scene will have multiple infoHotspots. So when you will uncomment, you should get an array of infoHotspots objects.

Comment: if i uncomment .populate('infoHotspots'),"infoHotspots": return nothing!
how to get an array of infoHotspots objects?

Comment: You have written var Scene = require('../models/setting'); I think it should be var Scene = require('../models/scene'); Also can you remove required: false after ref='InfoHotspot' in scene model and then try query with .populate('infoHotspots') again?

Comment: thanks for your help! but it didn't work